# Java ini4j - reading multiple options from .ini file

Tags: java, ini4j

I'm trying to **read multiple values using ini4j**, the docs say it should be possible with the Options class.

Here is my **sample .ini file** (./dwarfs.ini)

```
[dopey]
age = 23
fortuneNumber = 11
fortuneNumber = 33
fortuneNumber = 55
```

**here is the code** to read it:

```
Ini ini = new Ini();
Config conf = new Config();
conf.setMultiOption(true);
ini.setConfig(conf);
ini.load(new FileReader("./dwarfs.ini"));
```

but **fortuneNumber** property is just 55 after reading and I'd want it to be an array or a list, anything.

Comment: How are you retrieving the value of "fortuneNumber"?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose like this: ini.fetch("dopey", "fortuneNumber");

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I've also tried calling fetch multiple times, but it always reports just the last value from ini file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web presence for the [ini4j project](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/index.html) contains (among others) very simple [tutorials](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/IniTutorial.java.html). One of these tutorials explains, how to retrieve multiple values. How could you expect to get a list or an array, when using a fetch method that returns a single reference? Look at the [API](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html)!

In the tutorial, there is a part explaining multi values:

> [ini4j] library introduces MultiMap interface, which is extends normal
>   Map, but allows multiply values per keys. You can simply index values
>   for a given key, similar to indexed properties in JavaBeans api.

There is also an example:

```
String n1 = sneezy.get("fortuneNumber", 0);  // = 11
String n2 = sneezy.get("fortuneNumber", 1);  // = 22
String n3 = sneezy.get("fortuneNumber", 2);  // = 33
String n4 = sneezy.get("fortuneNumber", 3);  // = 44
```

In this example, sneezy is a `Section`, but it should also work with an `Ini`.

And just to make it complete: An `Ini` also knows a method `List<V> getAll(Object key)`.

Comment: uh, oh, I was looking at those tutorials but couldn't find what i was looking for.. don't know how i was looking for  it, maybe was too sleepy. Thanks so much for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

to handle mutliple properties in section use following code :

```
Ini oINI = new Wini();
Config conf = new Config();
conf.setMultiOption(true);
oINI.setConfig(conf);
oINI.load(new File("....../myfile.ini"));
```

Do not directly open the INI file in the class creation, set options before, otherwise the options won't be used and by default MultiOption si set to "false".

Have searched a while for this solution.

Comment: So you just copied the code from the original question?

Answer (score -1):

1. you need setConfig first, and then load file.
2. you need use List to handle multiple same values.

here the example:

```
Ini ini = new Wini();

Config config = new Config();
config.setMultiOption(true);
config.setMultiSection(true);

ini.setConfig(config);   //set config

ini.load(new File(filename));      // load AFTER setConfig

for (String sectionName : ini.keySet()) {
    List<Section> sectionList = ini.getAll(sectionName);  // use List
    for (Section section : sectionList) {
        for (String optionName : section.keySet()) {
            List<String> optionList = section.getAll(optionName);
            for (String optionVaule : optionList) {
                System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", sectionName, optionName, optionVaule);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here the out put:

```
dopey age 23
dopey fortuneNumber 11
dopey fortuneNumber 33
dopey fortuneNumber 55
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not appreciated at StackOverflow. Please explain why and how your code solves the problem mentioned in the question.